# Faster way to get files of a folder than StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync()?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10

[StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/BR227276.aspx) is incredibly slow:

- ~7 seconds for a folder with ~3500 files

Back in Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight, I was able to get the content of the CameraRoll much faster (via the [MediaLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx)):

- <1 second for the same amount of files

Are there any possibilities to speedup `GetFilesAsync` up, or is there any alternative for getting files of a folder?

I need the photo files to immediately extract information such as the **Geotag** or **DateTaken**. You can see how fast they loaded with Silverlight in my app [GeoPhoto](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfj0f2) - which I am now trying to port to UWP. I've already implemented caching (mapping geotag and DateTaken with the picture path), so I would only need the picture path for subsequent app starts. Photos not yet cached could then be displayed later (after the long `GetFilesAsync`-call), but it is important to give the user something he can interact with immediately after he launched the app.

Comment: Have you tried the `Windows.Storage.BulkAccess` namespace? `FileInformationFactory.GetFilesAsync` and `FileInformationFactory.GetVirtualizedFilesVector` may be faster.

Comment: @RaymondChen - I just tried the `FileInformationFactory.GetFilesAsync` method to see if it were faster as I'd never used it before ... in a lame example I baked up with 10500 files, it's 45-60 seconds to return, similar to `StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync` times.

Comment: Is your folder in an indexed location (like a library)? If not, then there's no choice but to hit the disk. Also, did you try `GetVirtualizedFilesVector`? My guess is that the virtualized vector has less work to do up front because it can produce the contents lazily.

Comment: @tipa Could you add the requirements for your use case? Do you need all the files in the directory to display them in a list? Or do you need them in your code behind and search for files. Such details might help finding a solution.

Comment: @Herdo I've added the requirements for my use-case. Hope it helps finding a solution.

Comment: @tipa Would processing/getting the files in chunks be an option for you? Or do you need ALL at the start?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you've read this: https://www.suchan.cz/2014/07/file-io-best-practices-in-windows-and-phone-apps-part-1-available-apis-and-file-exists-checking/

> **Windows 8.1** - finally on Windows 8.1 the fastest method is the new StorageFolder.TryGetItemAsync method, but only by a slim margin when
>   comparing to other methods. The main benefit here is definitely the
>   simple code required without any Exception catching if the file does
>   not exists. The results for sync methods are similar to Windows 8
>   platform, if original synchronization context is not required, the
>   sync methods are a better choice.
>
> In short, for checking if target file exists, on WP8 and WP8.1 Silverlight the fastest method is File.Exists, on Windows 8 and WP8.1
>   XAML you should use StorageFolder.GetFileAsync, and on Windows 8.1 use
>   the new method StorageFolder.TryGetItemAsync. **Do NOT use the iteration
>   of StorageFiles returned from StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync on any
>   platform, it is terribly slow.** Also if you don't need co continue on
>   the original thread, you can use the synchronous alternatives on WP8.1
>   XAML, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 platforms.

or something like this?

```
StorageFolder.GetItemsAsync(UInt32, UInt32)
```

to fetch the first X number of files to give the user immediate feedback that you desire.  After that load the rest.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227287.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Since my original answer seemed not to be helpful, I hope this one will be matching your problem.

I created a folder with ~4000 files, just for testing and used a Stopwatch for taking the time.
Just reading each item in the folder took:

> `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()`: **0.2 secs**
>
> `Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync` **~5.5 secs**

Executing both mulitple times and in different order

I understand that this just gives you the file names as string, but depending on the library you use for reading the pictures, this might still help you.

Original Answer:
When you got the *Path* as string (e.g from `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path`) you may use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(string path)`. It does not return specific objects, but the path as string. You can use those with the static class `System.IO.File`.

It also allows you to pass a searchPattern, which allows you to use placeholders like * and **?** and it's working synchronously, but retrieving files via this method works really quick.

Comment: The question is not only old but also reasonably clear about the lack of speed problem. How does your answer address that?